# updating mysql table data by 2 users at the same time

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working with a online game android app with php as server side.
In one place now i am stuck.

I want that 2 users will play a game when both are online and is connecting to the same game, when connected then i am calling a php url which is updating the start time of both the user in a single table based on their emailids, below in my php code for doing this--

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("update user_game_status 
                        set game_score=?,time=? 
                        where emailid=? 
                        and game_id=? 
                        and gstatus=1 
                        and gplay_code=?");

$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $game_score,$time,$email,$game_id,$gplay_code);
$stmt->execute();

$rows=mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
$stmt->close();
```

But the problem i am facing is, the time is updated only for 1 user, means whoever is entered first in the game his time is getting upadted but the 2nd user who joined his time is not getting updated. The url is called for both the users at the same time.

Can anyone show me the path which i am missing. Thanks

Comment: pls let me also know the reason for the -1 voting

Comment: i think i am asking the question with proper explanation

Comment: This code will update only one persons record. Do you call this once for each gamer?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  yes, from both the users app individually this url will be call, but the url will be called at the same time

Comment: The same time should not be an issue. MySQL will look after that all for you. Are you sure this code has been called by Both users? Do you see 2 entries in the apache log saying it was called twice

Comment: sorry to ask but where can i see the apache log, i am working in remote server in phpmyadmin

Comment: I would hope either using ssh or from the admin panel

Comment: ok let me check and confirm, thnx'

Comment: not getting any log in my phpmyadmin

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP for maintaining MySQL databases. It does not log anything. You need to check with your host where they place Apache and PHP log files. While developing you are definitely going to need to look at the PHP logfiles

Answer (score 0):

How does the `user_game_status` table look like?

You can use automatic update for `datetime` and `timestamp` so you do not have to include that into your query. If anyone changes that row the time will updated automatically. More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: hi, according to my app, when both users join the same game, then only my url is getting called and need to update the game starting time of both the users based on their emailid in the same table

Comment: But now what happening is, only 1 users record is getting updated, whichever mysql is getting first